# DataSet will not delete

Tags: c#, database, listbox

What I'm trying to do is to put a set of records from a database into a listbox,selecting a row from that listbox will show its child records in another listbox and delete the selected child record when a button is pressed.The first part works ok, I'm having trouble with the deletion,it doesn't happen.Why's that?

```
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
      comm.CommandText = "Select * From Director;";
      comm.Connection = conn;
      da.SelectCommand = comm;
      da.Fill(ds, "Director");
      comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

      SqlCommand commf = new SqlCommand();
      commf.CommandText = "Select * From Film;";
      commf.Connection = conn;
      daf.SelectCommand = commf;
      daf.Fill(ds, "Film");
      commf.ExecuteNonQuery();
      ds.Tables["Director"].Constraints.Add("PK_Director", ds.Tables["Director"].Columns["id"], true);
      ds.Tables["Film"].Constraints.Add("PK_Film", ds.Tables["Film"].Columns["id"], true);
      ds.Relations.Add("fk_FilmDir", ds.Tables["Director"].Columns["ID"], ds.Tables["Film"].Columns["Id_director"]);

      SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(daf);
      daf.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand();
      listBoxparent.DataSource = d
      listBoxparent.DisplayMember = "Director.FirstName";            
      listBoxparent.ValueMember = "Director.FirstName";
      listBoxchildren.DataSource = ds;   
      listBoxchildren.DisplayMember = "Director.fk_FilmDir.title";

      conn.Close();
      }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         int ind = listBoxchildren.SelectedIndex;
         listBoxchildren.DataSource = null;

         int idd= ds.Tables["Film"].Rows[ind].Field<int>("ID");
         ds.Tables["Film"].Rows.Remove(ds.Tables["Film"].Rows.Find(idd));    
         daf.Update(ds, "Film");

         listBoxchildren.DataSource = ds;
         listBoxchildren.DisplayMember = "Director.fk_FilmDir.title";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have an Update and Delete commands under the DataSet. also check that you have a primary key in the table in the DB.

Comment: Checked.Added
           `daf.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("Delete from film where Id= @fid");
            daf.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("@fid",SqlDbType.Int);
            daf.DeleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fid", idd);`

Comment: Where do you still see the rows, ds/listBoxchildren, both?

Comment: Found the problem,the delete command wasn't executed because the state of the modified row was changing too fast. Was going from `Deleted` to `Detached` so I had to use `AcceptChanges()` a little bit later.